# Get value of hash key without loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the value of `id` returned from the `response.body` function. The only way I got it to work is to loop on elements then assign `$record_id` to it.

```
JSON.parse(response.body).each do | k , v | 
  if k == 'id'
    $record_id = v
  end
```

I have similar functions like above used in my code, with the result that the script started to take a long time before it finishes.

Is there is a way I could get the value of first hash without looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

record_id = JSON.parse(response.body)["id"]

Answer (score 2):

Form the ruby documentation of [JSON.parse](http://ttp://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html):

```
my_hash = JSON.parse('{"hello": "goodbye"}')
puts my_hash["hello"] => "goodbye"
```